# How to reconstruct normal from depth without artifacts on edge?

Tags: opengl, graphics

Recently I'm working on my SSAO implementation, for my engine, I would like to add support for both forward and deferred renderer, thus I choose to use depth-only approach and reconstruct normal from depth map, here is the code:

```
//Restore view space position with non-linear depth
vec3 viewPos = getPosition(uv, depth, invProjMat);
//Restore view space normal
vec3 normal = normalize(cross(dFdx(viewPos), dFdy(viewPos)));
```

Then I apply this normal onto my SSAO implementation, it achieve quite a good result mostly, except for the edge:

[image]

I'm sure that's because the discontinuous normal on edge, but I have no idea how to fix it. So is there any approach to avoid the artifact on the edge when reconstructing normal from depth? THX.

[image]

Comment: The right way to do it is to render normals to a gbuffer. With only depth you are never going to do well on edges. You can do some heuristic but it will never be right all of the time. Even if you render object uids it will break for one pixel wide lines. If you really want to do this, make a filter based on depth instead of dFd*. Instead of dFdx(pos) you can do value(pos-1) - value(pos+1). And now make a filter that does different things if the two values are too far apart. But again this will fail when shading for example a single pixel.

Comment: @starmole: Why is that not an answer?

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to completely get rid of all artifacts except by generating a normals gbuffer. But there's a solution for reconstructing normals that gives you much better results:

What I do in my engine is, I take 5 depth samples for normal reconstruction. They are positioned like a cross. The center sample is the pixel you're currently rendering and you sample the pixel above, left, right and below that center sample. Then for normal reconstruction you simply take the closest Y sample (either the one above or below the center sample) and the closest X sample (either the one left or right of the center sample) relative to the center sample. This gets rid of those normal artiftacts in 99% of the cases, but it introduces branching and needs more texture samples. Therefore it is quite a bit slower than just doing what you're doing already.

Classic normal reconstruction:
[image: classic normal reconstruction]

Improved (cross pattern) normal reconstruction:
[image: improved (cross pattern) normal reconstruction]

Classic normal reconstruction with SSAO:
[image: classic normal reconstruction with SSAO]

Improved (cross pattern) normal reconstruction with SSAO:
[image: improved (cross pattern) normal reconstruction with SSAO]
(excuse my outdated SSAO screenshots)

Also please note that using `dFdx()` and `dFdy()` will probably always result in more artifacts than just sampling the depth texture three times (because there is no guarante that the values returned by `dFdx()` or `dFdy()` will be accurate), which is clearly the case in your example.